# Synaptic failing to launch on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, synaptic

I have just done a clean install of 17.10 I am finding that synaptic package manager won't work:

```
synaptic-pkexec
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(synaptic:9019): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Also finding that after installing Shotcut from Snap I get the following error:
'This program requires SDL2' I wonder if it's related?
Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your login screen, click the little cog wheel icon, and switch to `gnome on xorg`, and Synaptic (and some other apps) will now launch without difficulty. It's a Wayland problem.

Comment: Now that's awesome. Thanks a lot.